# How to enabled wake on touch as part of Android source code build?

Tags: android, touch, android-source, wakeup

I need to figure out how to enable wake on touch with Android source build.

At present the device is awoken with the power button similar to a mobile phone but I need to be able to do this from touch. Main power on is via the button but I need to wake it up with touch after it has gone to sleep after the preset time.

Doing **cat /dev/input/event1** gives me data when the screen is touched, on or off so there is still power to the touch controller.

Anyone know if this can be done and if so, any pointers to the part of the OS that handles this?

Comment: This doesn't sound possible to me. I think it can only be done at OS level, not app level

Comment: This is what I am trying to work out how to do. I have the full source to build the OS so if this is possible, I can add the code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your code.

```java
WakeLock screenLock = ((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(
     PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "YOUR_TAG");
screenLock.acquire();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need this to work as part of the OS itself. I have the source so can modify anything required to add this feature.